# Save and Edit to DataBase(Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have Like button, when it pressed - controller action should add field to my dbTable("Likes"), 
and if button pressed again - it should remove Like from dbTable("Likes").
Here code(simplified):

```
var like = db.Likes.Find(id);

if (like == null)
{
    Like like = new Like("SomeData", UserPosedLike);    
    db.Add(like);
}
else 
{
    db.Likes.Remove(like);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

It's work fine at 95% of times, but if i press button very fast 2-3 times, it throws error – “Null ref”, some data in Like is NULL (but this data can’t be null, because it references to other dbField(User)). Also, sometimes it adds two likes, but it shouldn’t.

I think it happens because of:

First action(press) – read db, start processing.
Second action (second press) – read db, start processing. (first action not saved data yet).
First action(press) – save data.
Second action(pess) – save data.
Here we got 2 likes. Probably with “null error” similar problem.

I received advice to lock this block of code, but I think it’s wrong. Also I thinking about Optimistic Concurrency, currently reading about it.

I’m not good with db, any help will be great - good book, code, article or advice.
Thank you!

Comment: use async and await

Comment: another option, you can block multiple pressing via `jquery` or `javascript` . simply, you have to  make button `disable` when button pressed.

Comment: Are you using Ajax to implement the like button? also you could create a queue system that will be processed in the database. That way you can have reliable instructions that can be used to updated the database regardless of how many times the button is pressed.

Comment: Use use async() and await() methods, It's best in this scenario.

Comment: Read about transactions and how to deal with race conditions in EF  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don’t like «disable button» decision, because I feel it’s not right(if someone disabled scripts?). I want server-side check for it. I will read about async, await, queue and transactions, thhank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *read* and *write* in [transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).

```
using (var db = new YourContext())
{
    using (var t = db.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        try
        {
            var like = db.Likes.Find(id);

            if (like == null)
            {
                Like like = new Like("SomeData", UserPosedLike);    
                db.Add(like);
            }
            else 
            {
                db.Likes.Remove(like);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            t.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            t.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

> I received advice to lock this block of code, but I think it’s wrong.

It is wrong.

Also as someone has suggested in comments, you can prevent users from clicking a button multiple times. You could disable the button and add a spinner.

Comment: I feel like disable button not enough.
Disable button+transaction looks like best decision. Not shure about await/async/queue (did’n read about this yet). Thank you all for answers.

Comment: `I feel like disable button not enough` - Exactly, it's not enough, but it's very nice to have. I'm glad I could help you.